# Send header parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using this method for login:

```
  doLogin(username, password){
    return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password

    })
  }
```

And I wanna add header parameter to this scope:

```
  doLogin(username, password){
    return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }

    })
  }
```

I checked console and it didn't send header. What's wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the type of this.http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send your Headers inside a Json Variable called headers like:

`return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login', body, { headers: this.headers });`

You are sending the Headers inside your body.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Headers` from the http module of Angular:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
let header1 = 'test';
let header2 = 'test2';
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('header1', header1);
headers.append('header2', header1);

doLogin(username, password){
    return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password,
      headers: headers
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are sending the Headers inside your body.Try following code snippet

```
doLogin(username, password){
     var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

    return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login',{username:username,password:password},{headers:headers}) 

  }
```

If you want to POST using `x-www-form-urlencoded`
you can do this using `URLSearchParams` as the body of the request and angular will automatically set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode the body properly.

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);

this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login', body).map(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

if interest in send auth credentials

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization' , 'Basic ' +
        btoa(username
                + ':' + password));
    headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    this._http.get(url , {headers:headers});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(Config.BASE_URL + '/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password
    } , options)
```